# Antdesign disable tree tips

Tags: javascript, next.js, antd

Is it possible to disable hover tooltips or customize it?. [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY86D.jpg)

Try global css with next many variations, no result…

I couldn't find anything in the documentation of the antd. The antd selector also has such an element by default.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the title to a dom element. `title: <>leaf1-nonTooltips</>`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tree } from 'antd';
import type { TreeDataNode } from 'antd';

const treeData: TreeDataNode[] = [
  {
    title: 'parent 1-0',
    key: '0-0-0',
    disabled: true,
    children: [
      {
        title: <>leaf1-nonTooltips</>,
        key: '0-0-0-0',
        disableCheckbox: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'leaf2-tooltips',
        key: '0-0-0-1',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return <Tree defaultExpandAll treeData={treeData} />;
};

export default App;
```